# JPA select new with aggregate function on member collection

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have a query like the following:

```
Select new mypackage.MyClass( u, max(sc.serviceDate))
    from Unit u left join u.serviceCalls sc
    where u.organization.key = :organizationKey
```

So, my mapping is that I have a Unit, which has a collection of ServiceCalls (FetchType.LAZY), and also has an organization.  Each ServiceCall has a serviceDate.

In my query, I would like to select the entire Unit, but not all of the serviceCalls.  I would like to fetch the most recent serviceDate if one exists.

Attempting to execute the query through eclipselink on postgres gets me the following (I removed some selected fields from the query output)

```
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "t0.key" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
  Position: 8
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT t0.KEY, MAX(t1.service_date) FROM unit t0 LEFT OUTER JOIN service_call t1 ON (t1.unit_key = t0.KEY), organization t2 WHERE ((t2.KEY = ?) AND (t2.KEY = t0.organization_key))
```

It looks like max is being applied across all service calls instead of getting me the max for each unit.  Is there a way to do this or am I going to have to just getch all the service calls and get the max that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need a `group by u` at the end?

Comment: :). This is not as obvious as it is in hindsight. You would really think that something like `select u, count(u.serviceCalls) from Unit u` would be legal without a group by, since it's completely bleeding obvious what the grouping is (this is not your example, but it's not far off). But it isn't. We should write to the JPA spec maintenance committee and complain.

Comment: whew, you make me feel better.  Thanks again for your help on this, with the group by I was finally able to continue progress.